# How to Merge columns in crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am working on `crystal` report in visual studio 2008. In crystal report i have two field `BranchName` and `Types`. What i want is if `BranchName` and `Types` are same then merge all columns for that specific row and display only BranchName with **Bold** style in that row.

```
--------------------------------------
Branch Name  |  Types   |   Status   |
--------------------------------------
    abc      |    abc   |            |
--------------------------------------
    xyz      |    mnl   |            |
--------------------------------------
```

and i want it as

```
--------------------------------------
Branch Name  |  Types   |   Status   |
--------------------------------------
               abc                   |
------------------------------------- 
    xyz      |   mnl    |            |
--------------------------------------
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you show your code and what have you tried?

Comment: I think the answer to **Similar** kind of `question` is already given in `Stack-Overflow.` Kindly refer the **[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898886/merge-two-or-more-crystal-reports-to-a-single-pdf/6570369#6570369)**

Answer (score 0):

I did bit similar functionlity through supress field by condition ..

right click on field palced on report and click on button next to "supress" check box 
then add condition if `"Branch Name"` and  `"Types"` value are same return true else false

apply this condition for `Branch Name`  and `Status` fields

this will not print value for `Branch Name`  and `Status` when condition match

Answer (score 0):

I don't think merging is possible in crystal report but you can achive this using supress condition.

1. Create filed that extends from `Branch name to Status`.
2. Now create 3 filds individually for all 3 columns
3. Now write a supress condition for 3 individual columns as

   `If Branch name==Types
   true
   else false`
4. Create a similar condition for 3 individual columns as

   `If Branch name<>Types
       true
       else false`

Answer (score 0):

for merging in crystal report we need dynamic lines,but lines cant suppress in crystal report, there for we use a Text Object with border as a line, then you can use this condition for suppressing your line:

```
if BranchName = Types then true else false
```

you can suppress `BranchName` and  `Types` same as suppressing the line which i said befor and finally u can create a formula and write this in it:

```
if BranchName = Types then BranchName else ''
```

[image]