# Merge 2 reports into one crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have two reports both have different format, and now I need to merge them so I can have 2 pages instead of two reports, I'm using visual studio 2012, Thanks

Comment: you basically need to execute both reports one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some approaches to achieve this. I explain one by one.

**Approach 1 :** Use sub-report :- If you have a common parameter between both the report, then best approach this is use one report as a sub-report and second will treat as a main report. For this in main report, `Insert -> Sub-report` , map the both report and execute will give the desire result.

Check this (or search sub-report in google) :
[combine 2 crystal reports to 1 crystal reports](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0ff3563-ab14-4a4c-aecb-b15316f6d00c/how-to-combine-2-crystal-reports-to-1-crystal-reports-?forum=netfx64bit)

http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_subreport.htm

**Approach 2 :** this approach is simple, in the c# code generate both report then export into one pdf report. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898886/merge-two-or-more-crystal-reports-to-a-single-pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it creating a new report and adding 2 subreports and works perfect